# Problema com o comando PRINT em FORTRAN 95

Tags: fortran

Usei um comando `OPEN` para abrir um arquivo, depois usei o comando `WRITE` para escrever um valor no arquivo do tipo string. Porém, quando uso o comando `PRINT *`,(com o asterisco, que deveria ser o padrão de saída para a mensagem ser exibida na tela) depois do comando `OPEN` , a string que é colocada no `PRINT` não aparece na tela e fica armazena no arquivo que escrevi usando o comando `WRITE`.

Aparentemente, a saída padrão do comando `PRINT`, que deveria ser escrever o valor na tela, mudou para a unidade associada ao arquivo que abri usando o comando `OPEN`.

Como posso mudar isso?

Comment: Coloque seu código fonte para analizarmos

Answer (score 1):

Não lembro de ter enfrentado esse problema.
Teria como você inserir o trecho de código que está se referindo?

Uma ideia para resolver é testar com WRITE para escrever na tela:

```
WRITE(*,'(a)') mystring
```